# Number of permutations of the word TRAPPIST

Tags: probability, permutations

If the letters of the word TRAPPIST are randomly arranged from the probability that there is no string of consonants of length 6, i.e. 6 consonants are not next to each other. I have tried using 7C2 * 6!/(2!*2!) but I feel like this is completely wrong. Any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are six consonants and 2 vowels, so there are $\binom{8}{2}$ places to put the vowels.  Of those, only $3$ vowel placements leave six consecutive consonants.
So the probability is
$$
\frac{\binom{8}{2}-3}{\binom{8}{2}} = \frac{25}{28}
$$